# Remove CSS Class with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a nested div that gets loaded using PHP include. It gets to put two places, each inside a different parent div.

```
<div id="parent_div">
    <div id="contact_details_div" class="contact_details_div sameheight">
        <h3>Some Text</h3>
        Some additional Text    
    </div>
    <div id="contact_div" class="contact_div sameheight">
        Even more text
    </div>
</div>
```

The parent div can be one of two different ID's.

How, using jQuery or just Javascript, can I remove the class 'sameheight' when the parent div is a specific ID name?

This works but removes it from BOTH parent divs.

```
$( "#contact_details_div" ).removeClass( "sameheight" )
$( "#contact_div" ).removeClass( "sameheight" )
```

I'm guessing I need an IF statement but, not sure how to write it.

Comment: It sounds like you end up with HTML code where mutiple elements have the same `id`? That's not supposed to be the case, ever, and fixing that will also solve your problem. Remove the `id`s,  and you can do `$('#parent_div .contact_details_div')` to select a specific element as opposed to all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, jquery selectors work like css, so you can use a parent child selector:
(The following presumes you want the class applied when in `#parent_two` but not `#parent_one`:

```
$( "#parent_one #contact_details_div" ).removeClass( "sameheight" );
```

However, if the `sameheight` class is only being used to apply css styles, then it would make more sense to make your css more specific, so it only applies when its a child of the other div:

```
#parent_two .sameheight{...}
```

Then you want need the javascript

Comment: `#contact_details_div` is supposed to be unique, so while this is true, it should never be necessary to chain two ids in a selector.

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed!

Comment: @Chris,  each ID only appears on a page once. PHP loads them using an Include either in a sidebar, or on a page without a sidebar, so it should still be unique IDs.

Comment: @ChrisG certainly ids should be unique per page, and i personally never use ids for styling (BEM all the way), but what i imagine is happening here, is this pice of javascript is loaded globally, and `#contact_details_div` can appear in many different contexts

Comment: @Jason, that is correct.  My functions.js get's loaded globally.  The parent DIV is specific to different pages, so duplicate ID's never get posted on the same page.

Comment: My final JS looks like this:      $( "#contact_form_sidebar .contact_details_div" ).removeClass( "sameheight" )
 $( "#contact_form_sidebar .contact_div" ).removeClass( "sameheight" )

Comment: @Rick you can condense that down as well: `$( "#contact_form_sidebar .contact_div, #contact_form_sidebar .contact_details_div" ).removeClass( "sameheight" );`

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks Jason!